# Reset mysql root pass

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to reset the password for MySQL but all of the solutions I've found, nothing seems to work.  I'm using OSX Yosemite with MAMP and MySQL 5.6.20

I attempted to reset the password via MAMP to `pass` but it does not work

```
$mysql -u root -p
Enter password: pass
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
$
```

---

and none of this works

```
$mysql -uroot
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
$mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
$mysql -u root@localhost

 Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
 Your MySQL connection id is 62
 Server version: 5.6.20 Homebrew
 Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

 Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use magento
 ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'magento'

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('pass');
 ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('pass');
 ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'::1' = PASSWORD('pass');
 ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stop mysql server and restart it with --skip-grant-tables option.  That way it doesn't look at credentials when opening up a mysql shell

After that,

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
      ->                   WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Stop mysql server, and start it again

Comment: I attempted this but it still doesn't work.  Updated question with details of attempt.

Comment: when opening the terminal after adding skip-grant-table, use mysql -u root

Comment: Ha that's one way I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding some details to Justin’s Kiang answer (which help me, thanks!).
On my OS X Machine:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables
mysql -u root
```

and then the SQL code as per Justin’s answer:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
bye
```

And restarting the MySQL server again:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Adjust your path to mysql folder if needed.